# How to update product weight and Country of Manufacture using MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

How to update product's Weight and Country of Manufacture using MySQL query in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Comment: I got query for this. Thanks, whom viewed this question.

Comment: If you got an answer, then please write it here as an answer. Or delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

For weight you can use this query:

```
UPDATE
    catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ped
JOIN
    eav_attribute AS ea 
ON 
    ea.entity_type_id = 10
    AND ea.attribute_code = 'weight' 
    AND ped.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
SET 
    ped.value = {your new value}
WHERE 
    ped.entity_id = {the product id to update}
```

if you want to update the country of manufacturer

```
UPDATE
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pev
JOIN
    eav_attribute AS ea ON ea.entity_type_id = 10
    AND ea.attribute_code = 'country_of_manufacture' 
    AND pev.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
SET 
    pev.value = '{new country_id}'
WHERE 
    pev.entity_id = {the product id to update}
```

A list of countries that can be use can be found in this table "directory_country", use the country_id for the update

if you have the catalog product flat index enabled, don't forget to reindex after updating the values